# How to create C++ map - no instance of constructor

Tags: c++

```
std::map<string, bool> action_map = { 
    {'0_0', true}, {'0_1', false}, {'0_2', false}, {'0_3', false}, {'0_4', true},
    {'1_0', true}, {'1_1', false}, {'1_2', false}, {'1_3', true},
    {'2_0', true}, {'2_1', false}, {'2_2', false}, {'2_3', true},
    {'3_0', true}, {'3_1', false}, {'3_2', false}, {'3_3', true}
};
```

Error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::map<string, bool>' (aka 'map<basic_string<char>, bool>')
std::map<string, bool> action_map = { 
                       ^            ~
/bits/stl_map.h:290:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires at most 4 arguments, but 17 were provided
        map(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
        ^
/bits/stl_map.h:228:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires at most 3 arguments, but 17 were provided
      map(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
      ^
/bits/stl_map.h:256:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 17 were provided
        map(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
        ^
/bits/stl_map.h:194:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires at most 2 arguments, but 17 were provided
      map(const _Compare& __comp,
      ^
/bits/stl_map.h:240:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 17 were provided
      map(const map& __m, const allocator_type& __a)
      ^
/bits/stl_map.h:244:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 17 were provided
      map(map&& __m, const allocator_type& __a)
      ^
/bits/stl_map.h:250:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 17 were provided
      map(initializer_list<value_type> __l, const allocator_type& __a)
      ^
/bits/stl_map.h:273:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 17 were provided
        map(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
        ^
/bits/stl_map.h:207:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 17 were provided
      map(const map&) = default;
      ^
/bits/stl_map.h:215:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 17 were provided
      map(map&&) = default;
      ^
/bits/stl_map.h:236:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__a', but 17 arguments were provided
      map(const allocator_type& __a)
      ^
/bits/stl_map.h:185:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 17 were provided
      map() = default;
```

Comment: pay attention to your compiler warnings you should be getting `multi-character character constant` warnings

Answer (score 5):

In C++, single quotation marks `''` are used to represent characters (character constants).

To express strings, you should use double quotation marks `""`.

```
std::map<string, bool> action_map = { 
    {"0_0", true}, {"0_1", false}, {"0_2", false}, {"0_3", false}, {"0_4", true},
    {"1_0", true}, {"1_1", false}, {"1_2", false}, {"1_3", true},
    {"2_0", true}, {"2_1", false}, {"2_2", false}, {"2_3", true},
    {"3_0", true}, {"3_1", false}, {"3_2", false}, {"3_3", true}
};
```